# How can I reduce the color depth of a PNG file using Swift programatically

Tags: swift, png

I am using swift and need to send a png over bluetooth. I want to have to maximize the height/width while minimizing the memory size and am hoping reducing the color depth will do this for me. I saw some code for reducing from 32 to 16, but how would I get it down to 8? Can it go lower?

```
    //image: UIImage

    guard let imagePixels32Bit = image.pixelData32bitRGB() else {
        return
    }
    
    let imagePixels: [UInt8]
    

    // Convert 32bit color data to 16bit (565)
    var r: UInt8 = 0, g: UInt8 = 0
    var pixels = [UInt8]()
        
    for (i, value) in imagePixels32Bit.enumerated() {
        let j = i % 4
        if j == 0 {
            r = value
        }
        else if j == 1 {
            g = value
        }
        else if j == 2 {
            let b = value
                
            let rgb16 = (UInt16(r & 0xF8) << 8) | (UInt16(g & 0xFC) << 3) | UInt16(b >> 3)
            pixels.append(contentsOf: rgb16.toBytes)
        }
    }
    
    
    imagePixels = pixels
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go down to one bit per pixel grayscale if you like. Or you can have 1, 2, 4, or 8 bits per pixel referencing a table of RGB values ("indexed").

[PNG IHDR image types](https://www.w3.org/TR/png/#11IHDR):

[image: PNG IHDR image types]

You can use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) to write PNG images of any type.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. but I would like to convert a UIImage to any one of these types programatically. Possibly Indexed-colour with a 1 or 2 bit depth. I could also try with a Truecolour 8.

Comment: Use libpng or a Swift library like [swift-png](https://github.com/tayloraswift/swift-png). The UIImage `pngData()` will not give you the control you need.

Comment: The `-colors 2` and `-strip` commands work in ImageMagick to reduce the size. I guess I need to see if swift-png has the same functionality.